# Should the docker production image needs code as volume or not

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, docker

I am using docker and I mount my code in `/var/www/code` in host in my development.

Now when I want to release my stuff in production I have two doubts

1. Do I follow the same process and update the code in production host with deployment script
2. Or my production image does not have any host mounted volumes and even I put my code as part of image so that in production I don't need to grab any code from github.

I am not sure which way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid ways of doing things. If you use kubernetes, Amazon Container service etc you probably have to use option 2 as they do not support host mounted volumes. Option 2 is also more portable as you can move containers around on a multi-node docker swarm easily. However, if you already have a deployment system setup using chef or cloud-formation etc option 1 does allow for more generic containers which are not tied to versions of your code.

Volumes themselves can never be part of the image as they are always mounted from hosts. However, you can make a generic base image and then have docker file in your code repo with

```
from my-user/my-generic-base
ADD /code:/var/www/code
```

When you deploy your downstream container to dockerhub make sure you deploy it with a version number which indicates the code version it will run.

Comment: I want to use option 2. But if in my developement i have volumes , how can i make the image which does include that volume. Are there any links tut etch which i can see how to do option 2

Comment: did you find a way to use volumes in development and copy the app code into the container for production? @user3214546

Comment: For option 2 you put your docker file with your code and use the add command to pull all your source code or built artifact into the container.